# What does 1/p mean, where p represents a probability

Tags: probability, inverse, intuition

I was going through a text on Shanon's information theory, and I came across an expression for entropy containing log(1/p). What exactly does "1/p" for any probability "p" signify?

Comment: $\frac 1p$ is how surprised you would be, on a scale of $1$ to $\infty$, if the event actually happened.

Comment: If the probability $\ p\ $ of a success is positive, $\ \frac{1}{p}\ $ is the expected number of trials needed to get a success.

Comment: See the answers to [Does the reciprocal of a probability mean anything?]{https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/242999/6633) over on stats.SE.